# Difference between `info` and `pinfo`

Tags: documentation, info

What's the difference between `info` and `pinfo` besides color?

`pinfo` is:

> a program for viewing info files

while `info` is:

> Read documentation in Info format

I tried to search the web for the difference between these two command, but found no useful information.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`pinfo` was designed to emulate the behavior of the `lynx` web browser and make browsing info pages easier to do. Its interface and formatting abilities are somewhat more advanced than the original `info` was and it also supports viewing man pages including colorizing them. It has a little bit more understanding of the content it is viewing, and can extract and follow URLS. It has considerably more key-bindings which are also user configurable.

See the [pinfo documentation](http://pinfo.sourceforge.net/doc/pinfo.html).

Comment: or try `pinfo pinfo`